# Opening a Visual Studio 2010 Project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have an application on c# and sql client, visual studio 2010, I want to open the project on visual stdio 2008, I open new solution and add the project to him. but on run time I accept this error:
cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MDF database in your project is version 655, which indicates it was created on SQL Server 2008. The server you connect to only accepts version 612, which indicates is a SQL Server 2005. A database created on SQL Server 2008 cannot be downgraded to SQL Server 2005. You must make sure you develop your database for the correct target server version. Now you have to either upgrade your deployment site to SQL Server 2008, or copy all the content of your SQL Server 2008 database into a new SQL Server 2005 database.