# Database cannot be opened as it is version 655

Tags: sql-server-2008, version, aspnetdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening a Visual Studio 2010 Project in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980705/opening-a-visual-studio-2010-project-in-visual-studio-2008)

Just had a small question regarding the version problems in SQL Server. I created a web application on my system in MS visual Studio 2010 and I guess with a SQL Server 2008 because that was the default that comes MS Visual Studio. Then after creating the application on my system I wanted to test it on another system  but that system carried MS Visual Studio 2008 and I had various issues due to framework change.

So, I installed MS Visual Studio 2010 on that machine and then tried running the application. I did not have compatibility issues but when it is trying to connect to the database that is the default database ASPNETDb.MDf it is giving the error "The ASPNETDB.MDF caanot be opened as it is a higher version of 655 and the server is older version 612. It cannot be degraded". So, I am not sure what could be the problem. I did read a few threads but just wanted to put the question again as it seems to be a slightly different case.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the SQL Server version (7, 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2) there are editions (Standard, Enterprise, Web, express etc...) and internal SQL Server versions where the system tables/structures of SQL Server change from one version to another version.

These internal versions are stamped on the boot page of the database and the versions for each version are listed below.

SQL Server 7.0 515 
SQL Server 2000 539
SQL Server 2005 VARDECIMAL disabled 611
SQL Server 2005, VARDECIMAL enabled 612
SQL Server 2008 655
SQL Server 2008 R2 660

There is no easy way for you and the options are to create a new database on SQL Server 2005 and copy the contents.